# Selenium python select item in dropdown menu that is not visible and uses aria

Tags: python, html, selenium, wai-aria

I am using selenium with python to try and click through a dropdown menu. However the options the dropdown menu produces are not visible in the source code of the webpage.

I have not been able to find a way that lets me select an item in the dropdown by name.

So far I am able to login and click on the menu to produce the dropdown as such:

`courses = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Select a course...").click()`

However after this, I am not sure how to access and click the elements produced by the above click.

Here is a snippet of the HTML that activates the dropdown.

```
<a class="d2l-menuflyout-opener d2l-clickable" onclick="return false;" aria-haspopup="true">
<span class="d2l-menuflyout-text d2l-menuflyout-emphasis">Select a course...</span><span class="d2l-menuflyout-arrow d2l-menuflyout-arrow-open d2l_1_41_179"></span><span class="d2l-menuflyout-arrow d2l_1_40_548 d2l-menuflyout-arrow-closed"></span>
```

Here is a screenshot of what the menu looks like after the .click() call.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8Fae.png)

Once the menu opens, I am not sure how to select the one I want since I don't know how the values or id's of the options are stored as it is not in the source code.

Comment: you have to use explicit wait to wait for the elements which are produced by click and post the using any locator you can access them

Comment: thank you! so I see what you mean with something like this ```element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))``` but my problem is I don't know how to find the link I want to click since it is not visible in the HTML..

Comment: can you try `visibility_of_element_located`  instead of `presence_of_element_located`  with `xpath` in my answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have shared in your `html`, **Select a course...** is not a link text  it is under `span` tag you need to try alternative like

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//a/span[contains(text(),'Select a course')]").click()
```

Comment: Hi thanks! I still see that the click worked the way I did it (I see the drop down). Would I still not then be able to access somehow the items in the drop down ?